# How to resolve java.lang.module.ResolutionException in JDK9

Tags: java, java-9, java-platform-module-system

I am on build [109 of JDK9 with the Jigsaw build](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8161704).

I am trying a hello-world type of example just to get started with JDK9 modular development. When I launch the application, I am getting the following `RuntimeException` (I am providing the java launcher command as well):

```
C:\JDK9Tryouts\HelloWorld1>java -modulepath mods -m hello.world1\hello.world1.HelloWorld1

Error occurred during initialization of VM
java.lang.module.ResolutionException: Module hello.world1\hello.world1.HelloWorl
d1 not found
        at java.lang.module.Resolver.fail(java.base@9-ea/Resolver.java:796)
        at java.lang.module.Resolver.resolveRequires(java.base@9-ea/Resolver.jav
a:94)
        at java.lang.module.Configuration.resolveRequiresAndUses(java.base@9-ea/
Configuration.java:342)
        at jdk.internal.module.ModuleBootstrap.boot(java.base@9-ea/ModuleBootstr
ap.java:217)
        at java.lang.System.initPhase2(java.base@9-ea/System.java:1916)
```

As you can see I have set the `-modulepath` to refer to the directory which contains user defined modules.

What should I target in order to debug this.

Comment: If [user3054250's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36093473/2525313) does not help, could you share more about your setup? E.g., did you package your code as a module and put it into `mods`?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have the wrong slash `/`, I assume you want:

> java -mp mods -m hello.world1/hello.world1.HelloWorld1

Comment: The answer works on Windows. For example, I used `“C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9\bin”\java --module-path mods -m com.greetings/com.greetings.Main` on Winows.